# MISSING: Active setup control Library

Tags: vba, vb6

I'm trying to load an existing vb6 project but I'm getting the "Object Library not registered" pop up as I load and then when I build the project I'm getting 
 "MISSING: Active setup control Library". 
 This is even preventing me from using the Format() method. 
 Please provide some insite on correcting this. 
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It in Asctrls.ocx shipped with IE4 at least. It's not in Vista or VB6.